# Preventing rabbitmq-server from being restarted when upgrading erlang

Tags: erlang

Is it possible to prevent rabbitmq-server from being restarted during erlang upgrade?

As we know during erlang upgrade erlang-base.prerm script will be called.

This script will check if theres any Other services that depends to erlang.

If there is. it will try to stop the service, and start back when erlang upgrade completed.

```
case "$1" in
    remove|upgrade)
    echo -n "Searching for services which depend on erlang and should be stopped..."
    # find all init scripts and packages they belong
    inits=$(dpkg -S '/etc/init.d/*' 2>/dev/null | sed -e's:/etc/init.d/::')
    # filter the list of the packages
    packs=$(echo $inits | sed -e's/:[[:space:]]\+[^[:space:]]*//g' | sed -e's/ /\n/g' | sort -u)
    # find packages, which depend on erlang
    packs=$(dpkg -s $packs 2>/dev/null | egrep '^Package:|^Status:|^Depends' | awk '{if ($1 ~ /^Package:/) {package=$2;inst=0} else if ($0 ~ /^Status:.* installed$/) {inst=1} else if ((inst==1) && ($0 ~ /^Depends:.* erlang/)) {print package}}')
    # construct services list from the packages
    services=""
    for p in $packs ; do
        service=$(echo $inits | sed -e's/\([^:]\) /\1\n/g' | awk "/^$p:/ {print \$2}")
        services="$services $service"
    done
    services=$(echo $services | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e's/\(^[[:space:]]*\|[[:space:]]*$\)//g')

    if [ -z "$services" ] ; then
        echo "none found."
    else
        echo "found: $services."
        echo "Stopping services which depend on erlang"
        rl=$(runlevel | awk '{print $2}')
        failed=""
        for service in $services ; do
        if [ -f /usr/share/file-rc/rc -o -f /usr/lib/file-rc/rc ] && [ -f /etc/runlevel.conf ] ; then
            idl=$(filerc $rl $service)
        else
            idl=$(ls /etc/rc${rl}.d/S??${service} 2> /dev/null | head -1)
        fi
        if [ -n "$idl" ] ; then
            echo -n "  $service: stopping..."
            if $idl stop > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
            echo "done."
            else
            echo "failed. ($?)"
            failed="$failed $service"
            fi
        fi
```

Is there any way to prevent this from happen? i would like to manually restart rabbitmq-server..

Comment: It would be wise to mention which Linux distribution you are using.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil Debian 7 (wheezy)